# Hibernate 4: LazyInitializationException on EL expression

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

I have the following entity inheritance, let's start with the root (it's just a table with an auto-increment integer ID):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Contacts")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Contact implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    protected Integer id;

    ...
}
```

`OrganizationalUnit` is just a name plus an the inherited ID:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OrganizationalUnits")
public abstract class OrganizationalUnit extends Contact
{
    @Column
    protected String name;

    ...
}
```

`Organization` is just an empty entity (for being referenced):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Organizations")
public abstract class Organization extends OrganizationalUnit
{
    ...
}
```

Last but not least:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Companies")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "company")
public class Company extends Organization
{
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "dnd_type")
    private String dndType;

    ...
}
```

This makes a company have 3 columns/fields: an ID, a name, and a dnd type.

Each company is referenced from a document entity in the system (each document has an owning company):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Documents")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Document implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    protected Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "file_name")
    protected String fileName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    protected Company company;

    ...
}
```

Note the `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)` on the company relationship. **It's mandatory not to have LAZY here, using EAGER fetch type here FIXES the problem I'm talking about here** (*but I want to get it to work with LAZY, also because I'm using a code generator to re-generate the entity classes... and it has to work!*)

I'm referencing `Company`'s `dndType` for every document in a JSF page *pq-edit.xhtml* like:

```
<ui:include src="/subviews/repo-filename-dnd-panel.xhtml">
  <ui:param name="document" value="#{doc}" />
  <ui:param name="documentFileName" value="#{doc.fileName}" />
  <ui:param name="documentCompanyName" value="#{doc.company.name}" />
  <ui:param name="documentCompanyDndSuffix" value="#{doc.company.dndType}" /> <!-- EXCEPTION HERE -->
</ui:include>
```

These are just passed to a subview `/subviews/repo-filename-dnd-panel.xhtml`, where I just reference the params, e.g. `documentCompanyDndSuffix`, to construct some HTML.

What I get for `#{doc.company.dndType}` now is:

```
13:53:56,043 SEVERE [org.richfaces.log.Context] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) /subviews/repo-filename-dnd-panel.xhtml @14,63 type="doc-#{documentCompanyDndSuffix}": /pq-edit.xhtml @139,94 value="#{doc.company.dndType}": org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session: javax.el.ELException: /subviews/repo-filename-dnd-panel.xhtml @14,63 type="doc-#{documentCompanyDndSuffix}": /pq-edit.xhtml @139,94 value="#{doc.company.dndType}": org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDragSource.getType(UIDragSource.java:95) [richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.DragSourceRenderer.getOptions(DragSourceRenderer.java:55) [richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.DnDRenderBase.buildClientScript(DnDRenderBase.java:66) [richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.DnDRenderBase.buildAndStoreScript(DnDRenderBase.java:43) [richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.DnDRenderBase.doEncodeEnd(DnDRenderBase.java:74) [richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeEnd(RendererBase.java:175) [richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:276) [richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.encodeChildren(AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.java:57) [richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar:]
.
. lots of RichFaces and JSF stuff
.
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:626) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2033) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_02]
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:149) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:195) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at de.poyry.pqgenerator.model.Company_$$_javassist_22.getDndType(Company_$$_javassist_22.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor457.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_02]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_02]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_02]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.4.Final.jar:2011-11-22 20:01]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:67) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:44) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:50) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.4.Final.jar:2011-11-22 20:01]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 72 more
```

I have no clue why I get a LazyInitializationException here, given that the Company entity doesn't hint LAZY to Hibernate 4 and the previous call to `#{doc.company.name}` works fine.

**Update:**

I've recently tested this on GlassFish 3.1.2 and all is fine. So I'm beginning to believe it's some kind of JBoss AS 7 or rather JBoss AS transaction management issue/policy mismatch.

My assumption is that the company name was accessed and unproxied during some transaction and after the entity manager was closed the `dndType` is accessed which hasn't been unproxied yet (whereas the `name` has been)... it looks to me like an EJB transaction handling problem (where I really still have a deficit)...

I'll add more info here soon.

Comment: What transaction strategy are you using? It seems like there is no JPA session active, hence the message: `could not initialize proxy - no Session`. Could you perhaps share your persistence config?

Comment: Oops, I solved this some time ago. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the company wasn't fetched in the statement - that simple. I just had the occasional luck in similar situations that a transaction was still active, so this one appeared to be failing, but in fact the others did, too.

I failed to realize that when accessed from a JSF page, the method which got the list of documents from the DB has already run and the transaction was already gone.

Comment: i'm facing the same issue , i get lazyInitialization Exception evethough the reference is declared to be fetched eagerly .
could you please provide more  helpful details about the solution .

Comment: Use `JOIN FETCH` in your JPQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:
fetch = FetchType.EAGER
It resolves my problem.